# Get the classname of closest element matching specific criteria and apply to another element

Tags: jquery, closest

OK, this is a tricky one, and I'm in over my head. I can hack it up, but I'm trying to avoid that.

Here is a visual reference of what I'm trying to accomplish:

http://bit.ly/1vXUM6i

If you click on the "User Administration" link in the left nav, you'll see the content change in the center area, and the tab name and icon change down below. When you click a link, it grabs the class of that link and applies it to the tab, which changes it's icon. That all works great. But I also need it to work if you click a sub-link. So for example, if you click "subscribers" in the "user administration" category, you should also get the little people icon in the tab. Here's my current script:

```
$(document).on( 'click', 'nav a', function( event ) {  
event.preventDefault();
$("nav a").removeClass("active");
$(this).addClass("active");
$('#nav-tabs .ui-tabs-panel:visible').load(this.href);
$("#nav-tabs .ui-tabs-active a").text(this.text);
$('#nav-tabs .ui-tabs-active a').attr('class',
   function(i, c){
   return c.replace(/(^|\s)ui-icon-\S+/g, '');
   });
$("#nav-tabs .ui-tabs-active a").addClass(this.className);
$("#nav-tabs .ui-tabs-active a").attr("href",this.href);
});
```

I know I could just give every link in a category the classname of the parent link, but that seems kind of unnecessary. So I'm trying to figure out how to find the closest "ui-icon-*" class and capture that instead. I'm not smart enough to figure out the logic, but thought someone here might be.

Comment: When I was trying to debugging it, page hanged and showed blank page and multiple 404 error in console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use the `closest` jQuery function: http://api.jquery.com/closest/

It will traverse up the dom tree to find the first element which match the criteria. In you case it would be something like this.

```
$('nav a').click(function(e) {
  // This will return the <li class='category'>.
  var $category = $(this).closest('.category');
  // Get the link directly under the category.
  var $categoryLink = $category.find('> a');
  var categoryClass = $categoryLink.attr('class');
});
```